# programmatically silent/vibrate an iOS devise using swift2?

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7.1

I'm a new developer and would like to know how to `silent/vibrate` an IOS device through code(`swift2`), I don't care if it requires a **private** API. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to import the System Sound Services

```
import AudioToolbox.AudioServices
```

Then you can play the vibration alert "sound"

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
```

More information can be found in the Apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html